# Infowindow is rendering but empty Google Map VF

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to ask for some help as I am trying to implement Google map in VF page. I face problem with infowindow- it appears but empty. I will really appreciate any help.

**Apex Class**

```
global with sharing  class mapController {
    global List<Agency__c> mapController1 {get;set;}
  @RemoteAction  
   global static List<Agency__c> getAgency(){
        List<Agency__c> mapController1 = new List<Agency__c>();
       mapController1 = [SELECT ID, Type__c, Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s from Agency__c WHERE Location__Latitude__s != null AND Location__Longitude__s !=null ];
        return mapController1;
    }

}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showheader="false"  Controller="mapController" >
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDDBQ9XiZET7NaiVbpLXfmnVkJRemATUBs&callback=initMap"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var map;
 var popup_content = new Array();   


function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5074, 0.1278),
        zoom: 15
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    load();
}

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    function load() {
       Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.mapController.getAgency}',
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                    var id = result[i].Id;
                    var type = result[i].Type__c;
                    var lat = result[i].Location__Latitude__s;
                    var lng = result[i].Location__Longitude__s;
                    addMarker( id,type, lat, lng);
                }
            } else {
                alert(event.message);
            }
        },
        {escape: true}
    );

        function addMarker(id, type, lat, lng) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map,
            title: type
    });

            <apex:repeat value="{!mapController1}" var="loc" >
                popup_content.push("<b> Id: {!loc.Id} "); 
            </apex:repeat>  

                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: popup_content
        }); 

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }); 

            }

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in browsers developer tools? Are you able to see the markers? What doesn't work?

Comment: I am able to see the markers and the pop up but it is empty. It should include the Id of the Agency.

Comment: Do you see information with hardcoded content? Try adding `console.log` the value of `popup_content`

Comment: The <apex:repeat> is not working but I do not how and with what to change it and why it it not working.

Comment: JavaScript remoting is stateless, so you won't get the value of  property `mapController1` in apex:repeat but you would only inside the remote action call.. Check also this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106671/google-maps-api-multiple-markers-with-infowindows

Comment: And how I would get the values from apex then? With standard Controller? Could you give some example so I can see how exactly should be as now I am really confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the property `mapController1` would not be set by JavasScript remoting function because of obvious reason: its stateless transaction.

Hence `apex:repeat` doesn't works. Also keep an eye on for any JavaScript errors when something is not working as expected. Your example gives following error:

[image]

---

Now to solve the issue, you already have the data because of passing the id parameter to `addMarker()` function. Following in add marker works:

```
function addMarker(id, type, lat, lng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        title: type
    });

    var popup_content = "<b>record Id is " + id + ".";

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: popup_content
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }); 
}
```

Demo source code is [here](https://gist.github.com/rahuls91221/cfae3e8069781d0135df890909424c0c) for reference.

Output:
[image]

Comment: That solves the problem and now I completely understand the things! Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Nice, happy coding!